# How to remove label?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

How to remove label from **MultipleChoiceField** in template?

[image]

**forms.py:**

```
class RequirementAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES,)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('symbol',)
```

**template.html:**

```
{{ form }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions

1) Use `label=""` when inside your form definition

2) Override the label, if you are using an inherited form and don't have direct access

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field'].label = ''
```

Another possible option is to pass [`auto_id=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#configuring-form-elements-html-id-attributes-and-label-tags) into the form

Comment: Thanks! In the beginning I used `self.fields['symbol'].label = None` but it didnt work. Then after your answer I use `self.fields['field'].label = ''` and it works for me.